# Finding a function $f$ such that $f(x)=O(x^2)$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ , but the second derivative is unbounded

Tags: analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

I want to find a function $f:\Bbb{R}^n\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ such that:

- $1)$ $f(0)=f'(0)=0$;
- $2)$ exists $C>0$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $0\in\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $|f(x)|\leq C|x|^2$
- $3)$ there is no $K>0$ such that $$\left\vert\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i x_j(x)}\right\vert\leq K$$ for all $x$ with $|x|<1$ and $i,j\in\{1,\dots n\}.$

I started with the function $f(x_1,\dots, x_n)=\dfrac{2}{3}x_1^{3/2}$. I have

$$f'(x)=\left(\sqrt{x},0,\dots  0\right) \implies f'(0)=0 $$

Furthermore, $$\dfrac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_i^2}(x)=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}},$$

which is unbounded in $B_{1}(0)\subset \Bbb{R}^{n}$, so $f$ satisfies  the conditions $1$ and $3$.

However, $|f(x)|=\dfrac{2}{3}|x_1|^{3/2}\leq |x|...$ and I don't know if $f$ will satisfy condition $2)$.

Am I in the right way to find this function?

Comment: It should be pointed out that (2) is a strictly weaker condition than $\sqrt f$ (or $\lvert f\rvert^{1/2}$) being Lipschitz.

Comment: @Gae.S. you are right. How can I express it better in the title?

Comment: @Donca $\ f(x)\ =O(x^2)\ $ as $\ x\rightarrow0\ $

Comment: @Gae.S.thank you! Any hints to my question?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Your function $\ f(x)=\frac{2}{3}x_1^\frac{2}{3}\ $ doesn't satisfy condition $(2)$, because $\ \left|\frac{f(x)}{|x|^2}\right|=\left|\frac{2}{3\sqrt{x}_1}\right|\rightarrow0\ $ as $\ x\rightarrow0\ $.

I suggest you look at something like
$$
f(x)=\cases{0&if $\ x=0\ $\\
\int_\limits{0}^{\hspace{1em}x_1}y^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{\left|y\right|^n}\right)dy&otherwise,}
$$
for some suitably chosen $\ n\ $.

Comment: I'm confused.

We have 
$$f'(x)=2x_1\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^n}\right)-\frac{n}{x^{n-1}}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^n}\right)$$

The limit of $f'(x)$ approaching $0$ only exists if $n>1$, and it is in fact $0$ in this case. So, the condition $1$ is satisfied.

Also $|f(x)|\leq |x|^2$, so satisfies the condition $2$ for $C=1$ and $U=\Bbb{R}^{n}$

But for a proof to $3$, it is hard to see what can I do. The second derivative hasn't a simple expression,further do its norm.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion.  The problem is not as straightforward as I had initially thought.  The problem with my original suggestion is that there appears to be no value of $\ n\ $ for which the second derivative $\ \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x_1^2}\ $ exists at $\ x=0\ $.  Note, however, that for $\ n>1$ your expression for $\ f'\ $ is unbounded inside the unit sphere, so *integrating* that $\ f\ $ should give you a function which satisfies all your conditions.  I have updated my suggestion in the light of this observation.